# A way to keep a menu from flashing when using a hotkey

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm new into cocoa and I want to achieve just what the title suggests:

Is there a way (simple or tough) to prevent a hotkey linked to a menu item from flashing the corresponding menu (you know the blue flashing) when triggered?

Just to make this clearer, I already know about the acceptFirstResponder technique which helps achieve this kind of silence behavior without it being actually connected to a menu item (which is what I want to know if it is achievable or not).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have an NSResponder which is in the responder chain, you can do this:

```
#define keyModifierMask (NSShiftKeyMask|NSControlKeyMask|NSAlternateKeyMask|NSCommandKeyMask)

- (BOOL)performKeyEquivalent:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    if ([@"q" isEqualToString: [theEvent charactersIgnoringModifiers]]
        && ([theEvent modifierFlags]&keyModifierMask) == NSCommandKeyMask) {
        NSLog(@"Command-Q!");
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

`performKeyEquivalent` gives you a chance to "intercept" any key event, including those that would turn out to be a menu key equivalent.

In this case, Command-Q will now no longer flash the app's menu. (Obviously, you would probably want it to do something other than `NSLog()`.)

Comment: I see what you did there, very nice! But... I do not want to intercept the event. Instead, I want to know if it is programmatically possible to disable the flashing of a menu when hotkeyed without doing anything else. This is just like modifying the standard Cocoa UI so that the title bar is more thick and trying to achieve that in interface builder seems impossible but some people did it anyway. It's more of a low level trick that I'm looking for, sorry if I mislead you.

Comment: @altares - OK, I wasn't sure quite what you meant in your last paragraph, so I answered the wrong question. Not sure how to simply stop the flash without blocking or intercepting the event.